# Net Core + c# сколько пользователей сейчас в приложении?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть приложение без авторизации юзеров. Как понимать, у скольких человек сейчас открыто приложение. Скорее всего это надо делать через Session, но как?

Comment: тут смотрите: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/diagnostics/available-counters

Comment: Если приложение подключается к серверу, почему нельзя просто добавить методы Connect() => i++ и Disconnect() => i--, где i - private int. Эти методы будут вызываться при включении и выключении приложения. Конечно, лучше реализовать это, как Dictionary<Guid,User>, где Guid - Hwid компьютера или телефона, User - класс "пользователь", который подключился, но, если это нужно просто для подсчёта, то private int вполне должно хватить